# PHP Call to undefined method DOMElement

Tags: php, xml, oop, appendchild

I have wrap class for creating xml file and i dont know how to rewrite add() method to work correctly. Variable SHOPITEM should be parent element, but i dont know how to reach it in add method.

Any advice are welcome

```
  class Items {

    const XML_VERSION enter code here= '1.0';
    const XML_ENCODING = 'utf-8';
    const SHOP = 'SHOP';

    private $xml, $xmlElement;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->xml = new DOMDocument(self::XML_VERSION, self::XML_ENCODING);
        //$this->xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->xml->formatOutput = true;
        $this->xmlElement = $this->create(self::SHOP);
    }

    public function create($nodeName, $value = null) {
        return $this->xml->createElement($nodeName, $value);
    }

    public function add($object) {
        return $this->xmlElement->appendChild($object);
    }

    public function write() {
        $this->xml->appendChild($this->xmlElement);
        $this->xml->save("test.xml");
    }

}

$items = new Items();
$SHOPITEM = $items->create('SHOPITEM');
$product1 = $items->create('Product1', 'Some value 1');
$product2 = $items->create('Product2', 'Some value 2');

//this wont work
$SHOPITEM->add($product1);

//this works
$items->add($product1);
$items->add($product2);

//this works
$items->add($SHOPITEM);

$items->write();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$SHOPITEM`, `$product1` and `$product2` are instances of newly added node (i.e. of DOMElement class) because they are result of the statement

```
return $this->xml->createElement($nodeName, $value);
```

So they just do nat have a method `add($object)` that you want to use on them.

Comment: Can you give me advise, please, how to rewrite my method, so i can use add method ?

Comment: As far as I understand the logics you've tried to implement (or at least it seems to be so) your `Itmes` class is supposed to represent xml document which will have one element `SHOP` which will hold some other elements. If so than this means you have xmldoc with root element `SHOP` and than only plain elements in it, none of them to be nodes to hold other elements. If everything above is what you intended than you can just use `add($object)` method and providing some `DOMElement` for it as an argument. You colud use your `create` method to prepare such elements.

Comment: And ont more thing:if you feel like operating on xml structure via some wrapper than go for it and implement a wrapper that accepts only your abstractions, so you don't deal with DOMElemets on adding process, or creating process, or whatever. If not so -- than use plain PHP abilities for xml operation directly. Mixing both approaches is confusing because one part becomes higher abstracted than the other one.

Comment: I can't provide some example because short of time, sorry. Some hours later may be I'll manage that.

Comment: The structure of finall xml should be like `<shop><SHOPITEM><product1></product1><product2></product2></SHOPITEM></shop>`. This is mainly for my educational purpose, this class was a good idea for me but as as you wrote, maybe it is not. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: and what's the purpose of `SHOPITEM` node? there can be many of those inside `shop`?